# Setter not called in include

Tags: jsf, el

I have a problem with jsf in the following scenario all getters are called and everything looks good but I can't set values.

The first xhtml looks like this, manager is a managed bean containing a container named page where I get the content as ArrayList.:

```html
 <ui:repeat value="${manager.page.content}" var="entry">   
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="${entry.type eq 1}">
                            <ui:include  src="/entries/Question.xhtml">
                                <ui:param name="element" value="${entry}"/>
                            </ui:include>                
                            <br />
                        </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

The included xhtml has the following snippet:

```html
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:form id="foo">
            <h:outputLabel escape="false" value="${element.content}"/>
            <p:textEditor value="${element.answer}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="foo" actionListener="${element.submit}" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
            
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

element is of class "Question" which looks like this:

```
public class Question implements Content {

private int contentId;
private String content;
private String examplesolution;
private String author;
private Timestamp creation;
private String answer = "FOO";
.... (Here are all getters and setters automatically generated by netbeans)
```

When i open the page "Questions.xhtml" is included as intended and the outputlabel containing content is shown correctly. The texteditor also hast the value "FOO" written as intended but if i click the commandButton nothing happens and the value of answer is never changed.

I have several Question Objects on a site with different content, therefore i thought making Question a Bean is not a good idea? 
Can anyone spot the mistake i made?

Edit:
forgott to add the submit Method in the Question class:

```
public void submit(){ ... }
```

it does nothing special just give me some logging output at the moment

Comment: Is your action listerner being triggered?

Comment: No it isn't i forgot to add it to the code snippet but the only thing it should do is add a log entry. I also added logging events to the getter and setter and while the getter always appear in my logfile the setter never do

Comment: Tried without a repeat? Just a single 'entry' ?

Answer (score 0):

Your class is named "Question". In xhtml is named element, i'm missing something? I don't see variable "submit". Perhaps "submit" is method, then you need add curly braces "submit()".

Comment: Please put guesses as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the submit Method in the snippet, at the moment it is just a void Method that triggers a logging event but it is there (public void submit(){...}). I call it "element" because that's the name of the parameter i used ( <ui:param name="element" value="${entry}"/>) in the include statement. And the entity is found, the String content is displayed correctly

Comment: If submit is method you need to add "submit()", it's not a property of class.Did you try to add "()"

Comment: If curly braces are not needed. Try adding "action" instead of "actionListener".

Comment: @mario To the first guess in your answer - it seems to me that `<ui:repeat value="${manager.page.content}" var="entry">` is iterating over a collection of Questions, each of which is then exported as element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `#{}` instead of `${}`.

> All expressions that are evaluated immediately use the ${} delimiters and are always rvalue expressions. Expressions whose evaluation can be deferred use the #{} delimiters and can act as both rvalue and lvalue expressions.

Comment: The difference between `${}` and `#{}` is not there anymore in current JSF / Facelets if I remember correctly